# python numpy access list of arrays without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I have a list of arrays with variable length. 
I have something like that:

```
a=[np.array([0, 3, 4]), np.array([1, 8]), np.array([2, 5, 7]), np.array([6])]
```

And would like to extract from all arrays that contain more than one value all values but the first one. It is quite straight forward to do it in a for-loop but I would highly appreciate to know how to do it without a for loop to save time. My for-loop is like that:

```
duplicate_pos = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if len(a[i]) > 1:
            duplicate_pos.append(a[i][1:])
```

Thx a lot.

PS: Even though this is the first question I ever ask here, stackoverflow is my daily science companion since I started my PhD several years ago. Thx to this amazing community.

Comment: Despite your love for stackoverflow, this question better suites codereview...

Comment: I agree with @Francesco

Comment: Why do you think that doing it without `for` loop, it will save you time?...Did you try to profile it?

Comment: How to do `numpy` tasks without a loop is a very common type of SO question.  It belongs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the list contains numpy arrays I suspect you are hoping to replace the loop with a numpy operation, not just another form of Python iteration.  That can speed things up by moving the iteration to compiled code.  For small arrays it isn't faster because of a numpy overhead.

In this case you are starting with a list, not a 2d array, and the list contains arrays of varying size.  That's a good indicator that there isn't a pure numpy solution.

A cleaner version of your loop is (no need to use a index)

```
def foo(a):
   b=[]
   for i in a:
       if i.shape[0]>1:   # use len(i) if i might be a list
           b.append(i[1:])
   return b
```

But this is expressed nicely as a list comprehension

```
[i[1:] for i in a if i.shape[0]>1]
```

In `timeit` tests, this is 50% faster than the for loop.  But the test case is so small I wouldn't put too much stock in the time differences.

I expect the other iterators - generators, maps, itertools - will time about the same.  Others are welcome to elaborate on times.

`i[1:]` runs ok on a 1 (or 0) element array, so you might not need the `if` test. Or you could filter out empty arrays in another iteration.  For small lists, the iteration choice is usually a matter of style, `what expresses the task most clearly to the reader`, rather than a matter of time.

---

If the subarrays were all the same length, or possibly padded with something like `-1`, you could combine them into a 2d array, and select from that

```
A = np.vstack(a)
A[:,1:]
```

But `vstack` iterates on the list, turning each sub array into a 2d array before applying concatenate.  That alone makes it slower than the list solutions.

Comment: Thx. I put the _solved_ here because of the additional info provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) (to get rid of shorties) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (to slice):

```
b = map(lambda li: li[1:], filter(lambda li: len(li) > 1, a))

# [array([3, 4]), array([8]), array([5, 7])]
```

In Python3, `b` is a `map` object which can be listified like any other iterable via `list(b)`. In Python2, `map` returns a `list`.

Comment: Combining `filter` or `map` with `lambda` is really discouraged and does not make any performance improvement; most probably just the opposite, did you profile it against OP's method?

Comment: No, I did not and I do not think it does. It is however the only suggested way to avoid using the `for` keyword which is kind of indicated by the OP ;) Under the hood this cannot be done without a loop anyway (I would strongly assume).

Answer (score 2):

you can do that in one line as follows:

```
duplicate_pos = [i[1:] for i in a if len(i) != 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension list:

```
duplicate_pos = [subarray[1:] for subarray in a if len(subarray)>1]
```

Or if you are going to use the values only once you could use a generator

```
duplicate_pos = (subarray[1:] for subarray in a if len(subarray)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use pure `numpy` to solve this problem:

Numpy supports multidimensional arrays and has very fast `reduce`-like functions. But numpy requires multidimensional arrays to have a constant length in each dimension. So you *could* (not necessarily *should*) use a masked-array to solve this problem:

```
>>> a=[[0., 3, 4], [1, 8, np.nan], [2, 5, 7], [6, np.nan, np.nan]] # nan to fill the rows
>>> b = np.ma.masked_invalid(a)
>>> b
masked_array(
 data =
   [[0.0 3.0 4.0]
    [1.0 8.0 --]
    [2.0 5.0 7.0]
    [6.0 -- --]],
 mask =
   [[False False False]
    [False False  True]
    [False False False]
    [False  True  True]],
 fill_value = 1e+20)
```

To discard all rows only containing less than 2 elements use `count` (counts unmasked values in this case) followed by a boolean indexing:

```
>>> b[np.ma.count(b, axis=1) > 1][:,1:]
masked_array(
 data =
   [[3.0 4.0]
    [8.0 --]
    [5.0 7.0]],
 mask =
   [[False False]
    [False  True]
    [False False]],
 fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I've included the intermediate steps here:

```
>>> np.ma.count(b, axis=1)
array([3, 2, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
>>> np.ma.count(b, axis=1) > 1
array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> b[np.ma.count(b, axis=1) > 1]
masked_array(
 data =
   [[0.0 3.0 4.0]
    [1.0 8.0 --]
    [2.0 5.0 7.0]],
 mask =
   [[False False False]
    [False False  True]
    [False False False]],
 fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: Using `nan` turns the integer arrays into floats.

Comment: @hpaulj - This is just to illustrate how it could be done. It was just convenient to use `np.ma.masked_invalid` to create the masked array. In practice this would be rather done by some kind of preprocessing. The important point is just the `b[np.ma.count(b, axis=1) > 1][:,1:]`-line which replaces the `for`-loop.